# How do I save the data in a local JSON file as a variable in node?

Tags: json, node.js

[image]

The code above works however I would like to load the `searchStrings` array from a JSON file.

[image]

My goal is to have the json file on a shared drive so my coworkers are able to edit the names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
var someObject = require('./somefile.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON can be imported via `require` just like Node modules. (See [Ben Nadel's explanation](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2908-you-can-use-require-to-load-json-javascript-object-notation-files-in-node-js.htm).)

You would generally want to store it as a global variable, rather than re-loading it on every `keyup` event. So if the JSON is saved as `watchlist.json`, you could add

```
var watchlist = require('./watchlist');
```

at the top of your code. Then the search command could be written (without needing the `for` loop) as:

```
kitten = kitten.toLowerCase();
if (watchlist.entities.indexOf(kitten) !== -1) {
  alert('potential watchlist');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of Node you can simply use imports!

**CommonJs:**

```
const jsonContent = require('path/to/json/file.json')
```

**ES6:**

```
import jsonContent from 'path/to/json/file.json'
```

You can also import JSon files dinamically, take the following example:

```
if (condition) {
 const jsonContent = require('path/to/json/file.json')
 // Use JSon content as you prefer!
}
```

that way, you only load your JSon file if you really need it and your code will score better performances!

Do you prefer an old school approach?

**ES6:**

```
import fs from 'fs' // or const fs = require('fs') in CommonJs

const JSonFile = fs.readFileSync('path/to/json/file.json', 'utf8')
const toObject = JSON.parse(JSonFile)

// read properties from `toObject` constant!
```

Hope it helps :)